# Удаления нескольких файлов php

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

По нажатию на кнопку хочу удалить запись из бд по айди , а также картинки из папки img!В базе лежат имена картинок!Удалить запись из бд получаеться!А вот удалить картинки по id нет . Незнаю как ето реализовать!

```js
$('button).click(function(){
  let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'php/remove.php',
       data: { "id": id },
       dataType: "json",
       cache: false,
       success: function (remove) {
            console.log(remove);
       }
    });
});

<?php

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'carbase';
$db_username = 'mysql';
$db_password = 'mysql';
$db_table_to_show = 'cars';

$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());
$id = $_POST['id'];
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cars WHERE id = $id");
$rmfile = mysql_query("SELECT img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8 FROM cars WHERE id = $id");
unlink('/img/'$rmfile.'jpg');
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id='1111111'>Remove</button>
```

Comment: может прав не хватает, и лучше использовать абсолютные пути

Comment: Как мне кажеться проблема unlink('/img/'$rmfile.'jpg') тут , я хочу удалить не 1 картинку а несколько , надо както мож циклом!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Както так

```
// Декодим полученный запрос в ассоциативный массив
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rmfile)) {
    // Удаляем файлы
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        unlink('/img/'.$value.'jpg');
        // Ну и логируем для себя
        echo $key." = ".$value
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема что когда нажимаю ошибок нет , но и нечего не работает!И 
echo $key." = ".$value; нам нечего не выводит

Comment: а версия php какая?

Comment: Версия PHP 5.5  . Главное что ошибок нету.Но foreach не работает!

Comment: $rmfile = mysql_query("SELECT img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8 FROM cars WHERE id = '$id'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rmfile);

$test = $row[0];
unlink('../img/allbase'.$test.'jpg');
echo $test;

На выходе ошибка :
unlink(../img/allbasejpg): No such file or directory

Comment: Ну во первых unlink(../img/allbasejpg) нету точки, ну а если не может найти даже если она есть то укажите путь к папке img через getcwd()